# how to pass value from form to html-select

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, html-select

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/7/7/c5713a4e18c508dbc4bee8371f6936af-full.png

I want to pass a value from a flask form data to  as shown in image. I take informations from a database. Moreover, this data should be passed to the colorid form. For instance, when I select green from  part, it should be written as 1 in the colorid part.

```
@app.route("/editproduct/<string:id>",methods = ["GET","POST"])
def edit(id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        sorgu = "SELECT * FROM all_products where id = %s"
        result = cursor.execute(sorgu,(id,))
        if result > 0:
            product = cursor.fetchone()
            form = Form()
            form.name.data = product["name"]
        form.color.data = product["color"]
        form.category.data = product["category"]
        form.brand.data = product["brand"]
        form.colorid.data = product["colorid"]
        form.categoryid.data = product["categoryid"]
        form.brandid.data = product["brandid"]
        form.price.data = product["price"]
        form.price_currency.data = product["price_currency"]
       return render_template("product.html",form = form,product=product)
    else:
        return render_template("product.html")
else:
    form = Form(request.form)
    newName = form.name.data
    newColor = form.color.data
    newCategory = form.category.data
    newBrand = form.brand.data
    newColorid = form.colorid.data
    newCategoryid = form.categoryid.data
    newBrandid = form.brandid.data
    newPrice = form.price.data
    newPriceCurrency = form.price_currency.data
    sorgu2 = """UPDATE all_products Set name = %s,color = %s,category = 
    %s,brand = %s,colorid = %s,categoryid = %s,brandid = %s,price = 
    %s,price_currency = %s where id = %s """
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sorgu2, 
    (newName,newColor,newCategory,newBrand,newColorid,newCategoryid, 
    newBrandid,newPrice,newPriceCurrency,id))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("index"))


    <form method="POST">
    <div>
    {{ render_field(form.name,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.color,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.category,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.brand,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.colorid,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.categoryid,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.brandid,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.price,class = "form") }}
    {{ render_field(form.price_currency,class = "form") }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: There are issues with this. What happens if `if result > 0:` is not `True`, for example? That's a 500. The indentation needs fixing to understand this properly, but you haven't shown the actual form. Does it have a `SelectField`? Your query does `fetchone()` so even if landing on the page itself doesn't cause an internal server error, the user will only ever get 1 option anyway

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks I will add the  if result == 0   part.  About the indendation, i had to do it as written because stackoverflow gave error about posting. I am new user so i couldn't write it correctly sorry about that . Last of all, my form renders information from database (render_field()).